# Using pytube and I keep receiving the error: yt is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I'm trying to relearn python after a long break and I can not manage to get this piece of code to work, no matter what I do.
It just keeps telling me

```
  File "/Users/fletch/PycharmProjects/untitled1/YT Download.py", line 18, in <module>
    mp4files = yt.filter('mp4')
NameError: name 'yt' is not defined
```

The entire program looks like this

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
import pytube

# save path
from pytube import YouTube

SAVE_PATH = "/Users/fletch/Movies"

# Get Video URL from User
url = raw_input("Please input the link of the Video you want to download: \n".rstrip())

try:
    yt = YouTube(url)
except:
    print("Connection Error")

# Filters Out MP4 Files
mp4files = yt.filter('mp4')

# Set File Name
filename = raw_input("Please name your file: \n".rstrip())
yt.set_filename(filename)

# Get the Video
d_video = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension, mp4files[-1].resolution)
try:
    d_video.download(SAVE_PATH)
except:
    print("Unknown Error, Try Again Later")
print("Task Complete")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If `yt = YouTube(url)` raises an exception, `yt` is not defined.  In that case you probably want to quit, instead of trying to process a nonexistent video.

Comment: yt might not declared at that point, because if yt = YouTube(url) fails, except does not terminate the program. Python should handle this, and give a different error message, but worth a try.